# How to script this, so output is used as input?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to script this command

```
ffmpeg -i concat:file1.mp3\|file2.mp3 -acodec copy output.mp3
```

which merges `file1.mp3` and `file2.mp3` to become `output.mp3`.

The problem is that I have a lot more than 2 files that I would like to merge.

**Example**

```
ffmpeg -i concat:file1.mp3\|file2.mp3 -acodec copy output1.mp3
ffmpeg -i concat:output1.mp3\|file3.mp3 -acodec copy output2.mp3
ffmpeg -i concat:output2.mp3\|file4.mp3 -acodec copy output3.mp3
ffmpeg -i concat:output3.mp3\|file5.mp3 -acodec copy output4.mp3
```

`output4.mp3` is the result I am looking for.

The files are not actually nicely called "file" adn then a number, but `ls` lists them in the order they should be merged in.

**Question**

How can this be scripted, so I can execute it in a directory with either an even or odd number of files?

Comment: FFMPEG supports multiple input files, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `ffmpeg` supports more then two files and no file contains `|`, and there are not too many, you can do:
`ffmpeg -i concat:"$(ls|tr '\n' '|')" -acodec copy out.mp3`

if not:

```
for cfile in *.mp3; do
  ffmpeg -i concat:myout.mp3tmp1\|$cfile -acodec copy myout.mp3tmp2
  mv myout.mp3tmp2 myout.mp3tmp1
done
mv myout.mp3tmp1 <your final file name>
```

Comment: Excellent. The first worked. A small typo. -acondec should be -acodec

Answer (score 1):

If you can just concatenate all files in one wash, that'd be best. But a generic answer for your Bash question:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:file1.mp3\|file2.mp3 -acodec copy output1.mp3

for i in $(seq 1 10); do
    ffmpeg -i concat:output${i}.mp3\|file$((i + 2)).mp3 -acodec copy output$((i + 1)).mp3
done
```

Here `10` is two less than your total number of input files.